# Bind Different ItemsSource to DataGridComboBox from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

Greetings everybody,

i encountered a problem with binding a DataGridComboBox and a normal ComboBox when i wanted to refactor from code-behind to MVVM.

Why can't I bind a source to the DataGridComboBox which is outside (ObservableCollection in the ViewModel) the DG? How can i make it happen?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">     
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Index}"  IsReadOnly="True" Header="Index"  SortDirection="Ascending"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Header="Type" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CategoryID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Tried to use ElementName, RelativeSource, AncestorType within the binding - does not function.

Comment: While your refactoring to introduce MVVM to your application makes sense you should understand that MVVM is an architectural design pattern that structures your application. It has nothing to do with code-behind aka partial classes aka C# vs XAML. Code-behind is a simple C# file that is mapped to a XAML file via partial class and the x:Class attribute. There is nothing to convert from code-behind to MVVM because MVVM and code-behind (C#) are not mutual exclusive. You will always need C# to implement complex UI logic, and of course that logic belongs to the View - that's all that matters.

Comment: The columns of a DataGrid are abstract layout models that are not rendered and are therefore not part  of the visual tree which is the reason why your bindings won't resolve. The DataGrid, like every table in general, is made of rows and cells that map to a row. "Column" is just and abstraction to group cells. Data tables are usually row based, where each row represents a data set. In this context columns don't really exist. DataGrid is implemented based on that common data structure model. If you provide more conext we can help you to fix your issue.

Comment: In general for the DataGridComboBoxColumn applies: *"To populate the drop-down list, first set the ItemsSource property for the ComboBox by using one of the following options:

    A static resource. For more information, see StaticResource Markup Extension.

    An x:Static code entity. For more information, see x:Static Markup Extension.

    An inline collection of ComboBoxItem types.
"*

Comment: See the docs [DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples) for an example.